# Visual c++ and Window Services

Tags: c++, windows, service

here is the code of my program written in Visual C++ 6.0 :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h> 
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{

    while(true)
    {
        int sleepInterval = rand()%15;
        Sleep(sleepInterval*1000);

        WinExec("notepad.exe" ,SW_SHOWNORMAL);


    }
        return 0;
}
```

Then i move the *.exe file generated from this code and move it to my desktop. I start it from there.Everything works,i mean notepad editor windows are appearing from time to time.
 Then i created Windows Service with the following command from command prompt:
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>sc create ThemesService2 binPath= "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\win32apphelloworld.exe" DisplayName= "Themes Service2" start= auto

The result from the command prompt is this: [SC] CreateService SUCCESS
Up to here everything is ok - a service is created and it has to be started automatically when Windows starts. I reboot . Then nothing happens, the windows from the notepad does not appears. I open Services.msc from the Start Menu->Run. The service is there but it's status is empty, i mean its stsatus is not 'Started'. Its 'Startup Type' is 'Automatic' as it should be.
But it is not started. I tried to start it manually with right click of mouse and then click 'Start' and a meesage box appears saying : 'Error 1053:The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion' . Can someone tell me what is the reason this service is not starting?
Thanks

Comment: Services run in a different session, so you won't see any of the notepad windows.

Comment: Well, i didn't know this.Ok, but shouldn't the service status be still 'Started' even i don't see notepad windows when i inspect the service in Services.msc? At the moment it is not 'Started' which i understand myself as "Not running"?

Comment: Your `WinMain` never returns, which coincides with the error message you get. That said, I don't know whether you can create a service from a regular excusable. A service is required to implement certain callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

A Windows Service Program is not simply a C++ executable, it has to implement certain functionalities, such as providing a service entry point. In this case, you have to call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` (so that Windows knows it should start communicating with the service) but this won't be enough. See the [MSDN Documentation for writing Service Programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685967(VS.85).aspx).

Also, if you want the service to be able to interact with the desktop you need to check the 'Allow service to interact with desktop' in the service properties.

**EDIT**: If you just want to run a program automatically when Windows starts you can always [add it to the startup folder](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7) or to the [appropriate registry key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: The task scheduler is another place to register an application to run on certain events. It provides more flexibility than the startup folder, and cannot be disabled as easily.